# Expose specific path inside service with nginx ingress

Tags: kubernetes, service, nginx-ingress

I have service A and inside service there's /a-path. How can I only expose specific path inside the service on not expose the whole service.

Comment: Elaborate the question with example

Answer (score 2):

the following configuration will do this:

```
  rules:
  - host: service.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /a-path
        backend:
          serviceName: a-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: is it will expose a full a-svc service? I have a specific path inside the pod of the service. How can I expose it?

Comment: With the configuration, you can only access the /a-path of this service.

Comment: is the any way possible to expose specific path inside pod?